# Evaluating $\sum\limits_{i=\lceil \frac{n}{2}\rceil}^\infty\binom{2i}{n}\frac{1}{2^i}$

Tags: power-series

Let $a_n = \sum\limits_{i=\lceil \frac{n}{2}\rceil}^\infty\binom{2i}{n}\frac{1}{2^i}$. Prove that $a_{n+1} = 2a_n + a_{n-1}$.

I have tried considering the derivatives of $\frac{1}{1-x^2}=1+x^2+x^4+...$, and although this may work, it certainly does not seem like it would be the best way to go about solving this problem.

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: I'd look at $\sum_{j=n}^\infty\binom jn x^j$.

Comment: One little note: you can write this sum from $i=0$, too, since we have ${a\choose b}=0$ when $a\lt b$.

Comment: Also, note that _evaluating_ your sum isn't strictly necessary to prove what you're being asked to prove; you can use binomial identities to show the result without having to determine the actual values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as [Steven Stadnicki](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/785/steven-stadnicki)'s question [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3765892/evaluating-sum-limits-i-lceil-fracn2-rceil-infty-binom2in-frac1#comment7748155_3765892) states, you can also get the same result as what you're asking for by starting "from $i = 0$" because "$\binom{a}{b} = 0$ when $a \lt b$" (note $\binom{a}{b}$ means the number of ways to choose $b$ items from among $a$ items, but there are $0$ ways to do this if $b \gt a$).

Next, for positive natural numbers $n$ and $k$, [Pascal's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_rule) states

$$\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n - 1}{k} + \binom{n - 1}{k - 1} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

With positive natural numbers $i$ and $n$, this gives

$$\binom{2i}{n + 1} = \binom{2i - 1}{n + 1} + \binom{2i - 1}{n} \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Using \eqref{eq1A} on both terms of the RHS of \eqref{eq2A} gives

$$\binom{2i - 1}{n + 1} = \binom{2i - 2}{n + 1} + \binom{2i - 2}{n} \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

$$\binom{2i - 1}{n} = \binom{2i - 2}{n} + \binom{2i - 2}{n - 1} \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Substituting these into \eqref{eq2A}, multiplying both sides by $\frac{1}{2^{i}}$, summing from $i = 1$ to $\infty$, changing the summation indices on the RHS and making a few algebraic manipulations, you end up with

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\binom{2i}{n + 1} & = \binom{2i - 2}{n + 1} + 2\binom{2i - 2}{n} + \binom{2i - 2}{n - 1} \\
\binom{2i}{n + 1}\frac{1}{2^i} & = \frac{1}{2}\binom{2i - 2}{n + 1}\frac{1}{2^{i-1}} + \binom{2i - 2}{n}\frac{1}{2^{i-1}} + \frac{1}{2}\binom{2i - 2}{n - 1}\frac{1}{2^{i-1}} \\
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\binom{2i}{n + 1}\frac{1}{2^i} & = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\binom{2(i - 1)}{n + 1}\frac{1}{2^{i-1}} + \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\binom{2(i - 1)}{n}\frac{1}{2^{i-1}} + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\binom{2(i - 1)}{n - 1}\frac{1}{2^{i-1}} \\
a_{n+1} & = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\binom{2i}{n + 1}\frac{1}{2^{i}} + \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\binom{2i}{n}\frac{1}{2^{i}} + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\binom{2i}{n - 1}\frac{1}{2^{i}} \\
a_{n+1} & = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)a_{n+1} + a_{n} + \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)a_{n-1} \\
\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)a_{n+1} & = a_{n} + \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)a_{n-1} \\
a_{n+1} & = 2a_n + a_{n-1}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$